# Информационная модель системы

Tags: php, sql

Есть сайт и база данных. Нужно построить информационную модель системы. Это по базе ее нужно строить? Что-то читаю, но понять никак не могу. Можете объяснить простыми словами, что нужно сделать?

ER-диаграмма это информационная модель?

Answer (score 0):

Я склоняюсь, что тебе подойдет в этом случае UML диаграмма сценариев.

Answer (score 0):

есть несколько подходов к решению вопроса "построить информационную модель системы" - можно двигаться от хранилища, можно от процессов, можно от потока данных, можно от участников-акторов. Если "заказчик" знает об этом (это ваш преподаватель), то он вас проверяет. Если заказчик не знает об этом, а просто повторяет "умные слова", то сначала стоит переспросить что именно он имел в виду. Если уточнение не получено, то проще начать с неформального описания потоков данных (DFD). Причем проще по разным причинам и с разных точек зрения.

https://habr.com/company/trinion/blog/340064/

Дополнение: если вы не знакомы с предметом и заказчик не ваш преподаватель, не начинайте с зарегламентированного UML - и от исполнителя, и от ЗАКАЗЧИКА требуется умение работать с UML. Вы, как исполнитель, может и разберетесь...